# Eclipse console printing words incorrectly

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf

I was doing some pdf text extractions.
I have attached screenshot of a scenario where i faced the problem.

[image: Value of the text while debugging the code]

[image: Screenshot - The text printed to the console]

Why the eclipse console failed to print the word "**specification**"?

Instead it is printed as "**speci?cation**".

I can see the characters overlapped.

But during debugging the code, the same text is shown without a "question mark".

Is there any way to print the same text to the console?

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the "fi" ligature ("overlapping letters") that is a single character in Unicode. In the debugging view the Windows methods for drawing text are used; these know about Unicode and can render the ligature correctly.

The console view uses a certain encoding. When used with Windows the default is "cp1252", Codepage 1252, or ISO 8859. These encodings do not know this specific letter and cannot print it, so the question mark is used as substitute.

You can set the encoding for Eclipse in general via `Window > Preferences`, `General > Workspace`, `Text file encoding`. While I think it is a good idea to use UTF-8 everywhere it *may* lead to problems with existing files.

You can set the encoding per project in the project properties, category `Resource`.

If you just want to set the encoding for the console view, the least immersive solution, it is not exactly intuitive. The console view encoding is a property of the runtime configuration you use for running your project. `Run > Run Configurations...`, your run configuration, `Common`.

When you use one of these methods to set the encoding to UTF-8 then the ligature will be printed correctly to the console view.

Of course the more general settings only have effect if not overwritten by more specific ones (Workspace, Project, Run Configuration).

Answer (score 3):

I'm surely getting all the terminology wrong here, but the PDF is probably using a glyph for the "fi" combination that isn't part of the ASCII character set.  Thus it renders in the console as "?".  Notice in the middle part of the window that the "i" in "fi" is closer to the "f" than it would be if it were the ASCII sequence "f" followed by "i" and that the "i" is also missing the dot.

Comment: @Jeremy Thanks for your valuable answer :) :)